# Bind fields to selected article in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have a simple question, i hope ^^

I have a combobox "Article" and a textfield "Description".
After selecting a article OR loading the form with the pre selection i want to show the description of the selected article in the description field.

**How i can do this?**

[image: my situation at the moment]

I would like a simple "Article.Description" or "[Article].[Description]" and MS Access do the rest. But it doesnt work i think.
So i try to build a event handler for selecting another article to read the description manually - but it doesnt work.

**Thanks in Advance for any idea!**

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends upon where you are storing the Article and Description data.

Being generic:

Set the "Rowsource" for "Article" to something like this (where Table1 is your table holding the values)

```
SELECT Table1.Article, Table1.Description FROM Table1;
```

Make sure that the following properties are set for the Article control (these are their defaults)

```
Bound Column = 1
Column Count = 1
```

On the "After Update" event for the Article combo box enter this Event Procedure:

```
Me.Description = Me.Article.Column(1)
```

This will update the description field with the corresponding article description.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from [josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947863/josh) i could fix the problem.

Thats the new query for the article box.

```
SELECT [Number] & " - " & [Name] AS Article, Article.Id, Article.Description FROM Article;
```

With settings.

```
Bound Column: 2
Column count: 2
Column width: 4cm;0cm
```

And then the VBA script.

```
Private Sub Article_AfterUpdate()
    DescriptionField.Value = Article.Column(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Article_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

I'm using "Form_Current()" ("Form on Show") because if i use the buttons to switch the dataset i want to update the description. If i wouldnt do this i have an empty or wrong description.
Or is there another way to make this better?

Comment: I am glad you figured this out.  Can you mark the question as complete?